# adding linear layout to current view

Tags: android, layout

I'm sure this has come up often, but I couldn't find an exact solution for my issue. I'm simply trying to programmatically create a linear layout with a textview and 2 buttons and add it to the bottom of my fragment (which is also a linear layout). I.e. I want it to appear below the other views on the screen not the actual bottom. However, when I try to add it, it always appears at the top corner and not the end. Here's my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN); 

  TextView noteView = new TextView(getActivity());
    LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    noteView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    noteView.setText(noteText);

layout.addView(noteView);
getActivity().addContentView(layout, lparams);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add gravity to the LinearLayout?

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is to have your views line up relative to each other, perhaps it would be worth considering using a [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to accomplish a similar task.

If that's not an option for whatever reason, I think LayoutParams has a gravity option that can be set to bottom which will align views to the bottom of the parent view. I can't guarantee this will work though as I usually do not accomplish tasks like these programmatically.